# How to test hardware issue in a smartphone Android?

Tags: motherboard, smartphones, test-equipment

My smartphone (SM-A426B/DS) has the famous issue of boot-looping. I introduced it to a specialist of mobile repairs, he told me that it's a matter of motherboard so he cannot do anything (it means he tried to reinstall firmware and it was impossible, so I guess I could not too).

Aside from the problem that I don't know how to be obtain a Samsung SM-A426B motherboard, how can I check by myself which part of my hardware  is faulty and with which tools/equipment to use?

Clearly, how can I be sure this is really a motherboard issue, or anything else ? No professional will do anything (in my country) about it anyway, so I want to try it by my own.

Comment: This is a Technical support request — Questions asking about troubleshooting hardware or technical support for hardware are off-topic for Hardware Recommendations because the site is here to provide pre-purchase hardware recommendations and to recommend hardware for a specific task, rather than to support existing devices. You may get help on [Android Enthusiats](https://android.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Tetsujin Well, my problem is an hardware issue, this is not related to Android OS (what Android Enthusiats is for), so I don't get what's your point exactly. Your striking decision, in my opinion is clearly abusive, you clearly know I have to test my material for hardware recommendations and there is no specific hardware forum on stackexchange, besides you clearly know that's out of topic for Android, that takes the biscuit.